# Multiple accounts in the same wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, address, sub-address, account

In many questions here, I have found people talk of 'multiple accounts' or of a wallet with multiple accounts. I examined the **Monero GUI Wallet**, but I don't see an option for handling multiple accounts.

Are they talking about sub-addresses or is it possible to use more than one account with the same wallet application?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Are these multiple accounts linked or are they separate accounts? Is there anyway they’re linked as one being they’re from same accounts? Are they treated as individual accounts like one account in one wallet app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiple accounts feature is currently only available in `monero-wallet-cli`. The GUI does allow for a user to generate and subsequently use multiple subaddresses though (confined to the same account for now). Furthermore, the GUI contributors have stated intention of adding the multiple accounts feature. In fact, there's already a preliminary pull request open that would add support for this particular feature:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/pull/793

The pull request has to be optimized for the current user interface though before it will be merged / implemented. I personally think we'll see an implementation later this year.

As a side note, in case you are using `monero-wallet-cli`, you can create a new account by running the `account new` command. Subsequently, you can switch between accounts by utilizing the `account switch <index #>` command (note that the first account has an index of 0).